Any idea why I have discrepancies between Google Looker and the LSA platform?
I am looking at the costs for a date range in both a Google Looker report and in the GLSA platform.
Across all accounts the GLSA costs are lower than what shows in Google Looker. The date ranges match exactly and there are no filters.
Does the LSA platform have a more restrictive filter that only shows costs from undisputed leads or some other field?
